# Réponse à “En quoi consiste votre travail ?”

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

> En quoi consiste votre travail ?

Quelle est la structure grammaticale que l'on devrait utiliser dans la réponse ? Les réponses suivantes sont-elles correctes ?

> Mon travail consiste en opérer les patients.
>
> Mon travail consiste en les opérations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Grammaticalement

On utilisera la forme  **"*consister à*" + verbe**.

### Dans le contexte

Je n'utiliserais pas le verbe *consister* pour une action si courte, plutôt le verbe *être*:

> Mon travail est d'opérer des patients.

Ou mieux:

> Mon travail, c'est d'opérer des patients.

"Consister" fait plus penser à une description détaillée, une analyse en profondeur:

> Mon travail consiste principalement à passer les outils au chirurgien, vérifier le respect des règles d'hygiène, et coordonner les opérations".

Mais je ne suis pas sûr que telle était la question.

Comment: En fait, on pourrait même éviter de répéter "mon travail" et directement répondre "j'opère des patients"...

Answer (score 0):

La forme la plus correcte me semble

> Mon travail consiste **à** opérer les patients

ou

> Mon travail consiste en l'opération de patients

même si cette dernière me semble moins usuelle, en tout cas, l'usage d'un **nom pluriel** après **en** me semble vraiment bizarre.

Comment: pourqoui 'de' et pas 'des' patients? (puisque c'est un mot pluriel)

Comment: @Cloud mmmh je ne connaissait pas exactement la règle, puis je suis tombé sur ça ;)   https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-61719.php

Comment: les patients étant dénombrables, il faut mettre le pluriel après 'de'. selon moi 'de' ou 'des' pourraient marcher tous les deux. Mais je trouve que dans ce cas 'des' désigne en particulier les patients au lieu de parler des patients en général.